# How can I add a square image to a QRCode | Swift

Tags: swift, qr-code

Essentially I have the following QR Code function that successfully creates a QR code based on a given string - how can add a square image to the center of this QR code that is static no matter what string the code represents?

```
The following is the function I use to generate:
    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return UIImage(ciImage: output)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: It's just an image, so just draw your overlay image over it. The only problematic part is that you will have to add `filter.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")` to increase the correction level of the QR code. That will allow the QR code to be read even if part of it will be missing in the center.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to draw an overlay image - I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from one of my apps, only slightly commented.
The size calculations maybe won't be required for you app.

```
func generateImage(code: String, size pointSize: CGSize, logo: UIImage? = nil) -> UIImage? {
    let pixelScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let pixelSize = CGSize(width: pointSize.width * pixelScale, height: pointSize.height * pixelScale)

    guard
        let codeData = code.data(using: .isoLatin1),
        let generator = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
    else {
        return nil
    }

    generator.setValue(codeData, forKey: "inputMessage")
    // set higher self-correction level
    generator.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    guard let codeImage = generator.outputImage else {
        return nil
    }

    // calculate transform depending on required size
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(
        scaleX: pixelSize.width / codeImage.extent.width,
        y: pixelSize.height / codeImage.extent.height
    )

    let scaledCodeImage = UIImage(ciImage: codeImage.transformed(by: transform), scale: 0, orientation: .up)

    guard let logo = logo else {
        return scaledCodeImage
    }

    // create a drawing buffer
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pointSize, false, 0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    // draw QR code into the buffer
    scaledCodeImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pointSize))

    // calculate scale to cover the central 25% of the image
    let logoScaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.25
    // update depending on logo width/height ratio
    let logoScale = min(
        pointSize.width * logoScaleFactor / logo.size.width,
        pointSize.height * logoScaleFactor / logo.size.height
    )

    // size of the logo
    let logoSize = CGSize(width: logoScale * logo.size.width, height: logoScale * logo.size.height)

    // draw the logo
    logo.draw(in: CGRect(
        x: (pointSize.width - logoSize.width) / 2,
        y: (pointSize.height - logoSize.height) / 2,
        width: logoSize.width,
        height: logoSize.height
    ))

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
}
```

Comment: Why force unwrap the result if your are already returning an optional?

Comment: Btw the String Encoding should be [`isoLatin1`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator) **"To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an NSData object using the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding string encoding."**

Comment: @LeoDabus I fixed the encoding. I use QR codes only in ASCII contexts so the encoding never bothered me.